# Capturing variables in Ruby methods

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, closures

In CoffeeScript:

```
f = ->
  v = 5
  g = ->
    v
  g()

f() # returns 5 as expected
```

In Ruby:

```
def f
  v = 5
  def g
    v # undefined local variable or method `v' for main:Object (NameError)
  end
  g
end
f
```

Okay, so apparently JavaScript functions are set up to capture variables in the scope they are created in, but Ruby's methods are not. Is there a way to make Ruby methods behave like JavaScript functions in this regard?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have functions. It has methods and it has blocks. Methods have new scopes, blocks have nested scopes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Actually, as I learned from Fred's answer, Ruby has methods and **closures**. Blocks are just one of three kinds of closures in Ruby. There are also Lambdas and Procs.

Comment: Lambdas and Procs are just objects which are created by passing blocks to methods. (Or using the lambda literal syntax.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby has script scope, module/class/method definition scope and block scope. Only blocks create nested scopes. So, you need to use a block to define your method. Thankfully, there is a method for defining methods that takes a block:

```
def f
  v = 5
  define_method :g do
    v
  end
  g
end
f
# => 5
```

However, note that this does *not* do what you think it does (and neither does your original code). It does *not* define a method `g` nested in method `f`. Ruby doesn't have nested methods. Methods always belong to modules (classes are modules), they cannot belong to methods.

What this does is define a method `f`, which when you run it defines a method `g` and then calls that method.

Observe:

```
methods.include?(:g)
# => true
```

You have now defined a new top-level method (actually a private instance method of `Object`) called `g`, and you will define it over and over and over again, everytime `f` gets called.

What you probably want is a lambda:

```
def f
  v = 5
  g = -> { v }
  g.()
end
f
# => 5
```

In a comment to another answer you wrote:

> Okay, so I'm messing around with lambdas, and I noticed that anything I do to `v` inside of `g` is not reflected in `v` once `g` returns. Is there a way I can make my changes to `v` stick?

```
def f
  v = 5
  g = -> { v = 'Hello' }
  g.()
  v
end
f
# => 'Hello'
```

As you can see, the change to `v` *does* "stick" after `g` returns.

Comment: So, g.() is equivalent to g.call and g.call()! I did not know that.

Comment: @Fred, And there's g[]. The Proc#[] docs mention the syntax g.(),  and point out that g.() is syntactic sugar for g.call.  Matz must be really desperate to save 2 characters of typing!  But who likes reaching way up there for those parenthesis keys? And you have to hit shift anyway, so you aren't even saving any key strokes! In my opinion, it's really ugly syntax, and I won't be using it.

Comment: I deleted that comment because I realized that I had for gotten to *call* `g`. But thank you for the correction.

Comment: @7stud If we're going to spout our opinions, I'd like to say that `g.()` is very obviously a call to `g`, whereas `g.call` looks more like a call to a member *of `g`*. While both are technically the latter, I'd rather think of it as if I'm calling `g`, not calling a method on `g`. Therefore I'll be using `.()` where it seems applicable.

Comment: @anthropomorphic, `I'd like to say that g.() is very obviously a call to g, whereas g.call looks more like a call to a member of g` Huh?  They are both methods called by g, and one method is spelled '()', and the other is spelled 'call'.  Or in ruby speak, one sends the message '()' to g, and the other sends the message 'call' to g.  What's a `member of g`?

Comment: @7stud Generally speaking a member is something that is logically contained within an object. Maybe I'm not using the correct Ruby terminology - do you prefer 'attribute'? You are entirely correct, as I pointed out before, but I feel that `g.()` *looks* more like `g()` than `g.call` does, and that is a good thing, because I'd rather think of a Proc as being a procedure, rather than being an object containing a procedure, even though the former is technically untrue.

Answer (score 8):

You don't really define methods inside of methods in Ruby, but you can use `lambda`:

```
def f
  v = 5

  g = lambda do
    v
  end

  g.call
end
```

Comment: Yep. Ruby has real closures.

Comment: p.s. and you can also write `g[]` for short instead of `g.call` (and if you wanted to pass any arguments, you would put it in the brackets)

Comment: I really wish Ruby had `()` as an alias for `call`, so you could just do it JavaScript or Python style: `g()`.

Comment: Does anyone know why ruby uses brackets instead of parentheses for this?

Comment: The answer just occurred to me: if you could overload a `()` operator on `Proc`, then for consistency's sake you ought to be able to overload a `()` operator on any other class. Since Matz didn't want a call operator (for whatever reason(s)), we're left with `.()` or `[]`, being the closest alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no. Ruby's functions have different scoping rules than Javascript functions.

Longer answer is that you can define objects in Ruby that preserve the scope in which they are defined (called a closure). These are called lambdas, Procs, and blocks in Ruby. Look [here](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) for a quick overview.

Edit: blocks are not Ruby objects, but they can be converted into Procs, which are objects.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can learn what was in error. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the downvote was for this "Ruby's functions", as strictly there are no functions in Ruby, only methods and blocks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, for most consistency with your CoffeeScript code, you would probably write:

```
f = lambda do
  v = 5

  g = lambda do
    v
  end

  g[]
end
f[]
```

Answer (score 1):

A closure is a named block of code (a function in some languages, a lambda or proc in Ruby) with the following characteristics:

- It remembers the values of all variables that were available in the
  scope it was defined (outer scope), even when called on another scope
  or when those variables are no longer available (out of scope).
- It is an object. Hence, it can be assigned to a variable, passed around, called from within different scopes, etc.

Below is an example using a Lambda. The same could be done using a Proc.

```
minutes = 40
def meditate minutes
    return lambda { minutes }
end

p = meditate minutes
minutes = nil
p.call

# Output:
=> 40
```

Notice the lambda was created inside the meditate method, which took minutes as an argument. Later, when we called the lambda, the meditate method was already gone. We also set the value of minutes to nil. Nonetheless, the lambda remembered the value of "minutes".

Ruby has two types of closures: Lambdas and Procs.

Methods are not closures, neither are the Method objects. As stated by Yukihiro Matsumoto (Matz) in his book The Ruby Programming Language:

> One important difference between Method objects and Proc objects is that Method objects are not closures. Ruby's method are intended to be completely self-contained, and they never have access to local variables outside of their scope. The only binding retained by a Method object, therefore, is the value of self - the object on which the method is to be invoked.

See more at [this post about Methods in the Zen Ruby blog.](http://www.zenruby.info/2016/05/methods-in-ruby.html)